# Heroku help Permission denied how to open file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I get this error on Heroku:

```
 ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Rendered admin/xml/index.rhtml wi
    thin layouts/admin (87.7ms)
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed   in 89ms
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionView::Template::Error (Perm
    ission denied - /app/public/xml/preview.xml):
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     1: <% update_xml("preview") %
    >
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     2:
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     3:
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     4: <h2>Preview/publish</h2>
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/helpers/admin/xml_helper.rb
    :88:in `initialize'
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/helpers/admin/xml_helper.rb
    :88:in `open'
    ←[36m2011-09-25T00:24:51+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/helpers/admin/xml_helper.rb
```

My helper:

```
    File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/xml/#{output}.xml", "w") do |f|

           f.puts("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>")            
           f.puts("<site>")     

           f.puts("<general name='general' type='general'><imagePath>photographer/image/</imagePath><moviePath>../photographer/flv/</moviePath></general>")             
           f.puts("#{xmlmenu.to_xml}")
           f.puts("#{xmlmovies.to_xml}")                           
           f.puts("#{xmltextpages.to_xml}")

           f.puts("</site>")
        end 
end
```

How to fix this?
Or how to create this open file wit amazon S3 and authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only directory you can write to on Heroku is tmp.

Comment: How to open file on Amazon S3 and authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

The Cedar stack has a writable file system but it's only persistent for the life of the dyno and anything that's been written is only available to the dyno that wrote the file.

Comment: I am trying a solution with Amazon s3 but are runing into problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542898/ruby-and-amazon-s3-how-to-open-file-and-authicate